# I can't seem to compare two date objects. One from mongo, one generated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

edit, I've been able to work around this problem by comparing the values of the dates rather than the dates themselves:

```
$scope.entries[0].formattedDate === $scope.days[0]
$scope.entries[i].formattedDate.valueOf() === $scope.days[0].valueOf() //true
```

The goal of this angularjs program is to:

1. Generate the days in the current week (as an array of Javascript Date Objects)
2. Obtain a bunch of JSON objects from mongodb. (These objects have a property called "date." This "date" property is in the following format: `ISODate("2016-05-18T04:44:42.067Z")`
3. Compare each of the mongo items to a generated day, tell the user if any match (only the day! disregard time)

This is my code to generate the days of the week, and it works well:

```
$scope.getWeek = function (num) {
    var curr = new Date;
    curr.setDate(curr.getDate() - (num * 7));
    var days = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        days.push(new Date(curr.setDate(curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() + i)));
        days[i].setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    $scope.days = days;
};
```

I only want to know if the day matches, and not the time. I am using this function to strip the time from every item retrieved from Mongodb:

```
var removeHours = function (date) {
    date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return date;
};
```

When it comes to comparing the dates, I'm absolutely stuck! It seems like I've tried everything. When I console.log the two dates, they are identical. I'm probably not aware of something about JS objects and I'm hoping somebody can provide a simple, easy solution.

```
$scope.entries[i].formattedDate == $scope.days[0] // false
```

Comment: Try use valueOf,  ```$scope.entries[i].formattedDate.valueOf() === $scope.days[0].valueOf()```

Comment: `console.log($scope.entries[0].formattedDate.valueOf() === $scope.days[0].valueOf());` still is false. I really don't know ...

Comment: What dose ```console.log($scope.entries[0].formattedDate.valueOf() === $scope.days[0].valueOf());``` show?

Comment: it shows false. `console.log($scope.entries[0].formattedDate.valueOf() ,' ', $scope.days[i].valueOf());` shows `1464062400000 " " 1464494400000` $scope.days[i].valueOf() seems to have the same value no matter what date is given. And the value of that is different from the generated date...

Comment: ^ that last comment isn't true. I've got it working somehow by referring the the dates by their values... Not sure why this works, but comparing the actual date object doesn't work. hooray!

Comment: ```$scope.entries[i].formattedDate == $scope.days[0]```, you want to find the  sunday data?

Comment: Glad you solved it.